# Skip block in YAML files in GitLab based on condition

Tags: gitlab, yaml

I have a repo in GitLab. It contains a .gitlab-ci.yaml than has a variable called **VERSION**. I use this variable in regular .yaml files in the project as:

```yaml
...
  version: ${VERSION}
...
```

I want to make this YAML code block be omitted (or perhaps replaced by an empty string) if a specific version is provided.

### For example,

gitlab.ci-yml:

```yaml
variables:
  VERSION: 7
```

A regular YAML file:

```yaml
app1:
  name: my-app
  version: ${VERSION}
```

I want this block in the regular YAML file be skipped **if** version is 8. How can I do that?

***GitLab version: 13.12***

---

##### UPDATE

My YAML block `app1` also has `enabled: true` attribute. Is there a way to put a conditional statement instead of that `true`? For example,

```yaml
app1:
  name: my-app
  enabled: # SOME CONDITIONAL STATEMENT HERE
  version: ${VERSION}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of [rules:if](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) to specify when you want the job to run.

So in your particular case you would add this to your job (adding indentation spacing as needed):

```
rules:
  - if: '$VERSION != 8'
```

alternatively, you can specify that when it matches, not to run it:

```
rules:
  - if: '$VERSION == 8'
    when: never
```

Comment: But I don't want to skip a job. I want to skip a piece of YAML file if the version matches. Alternatively, my YAML has `enabled: true` field. Is there a way to put conditional statement instead of that `true` flag?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "a piece of YAML file" then, because adding a rule would skip the job, such as the "app1" job you've included in your example. "enabled" is also not a keyword listed in the YAML reference, so I'm not sure what that's supposed to do: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/